# Possible to paste content into a sheet that's not active?

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I need to paste some data into a sheet in Excel that's not active. Is that possible?

Every ten seconds content is copied from a different program (not excel) thanks to a script. I then need to paste the content into a background sheet in an excel workbook but I don't want the screen to flash every time, activating the background sheet where the data goes and then back to the main sheet.

The content is already in the clipboard when the macro is started.

This is the current code which works but make the screen flash.

```
Sub pastecontent()
Sheets("searchresult").UsedRange.ClearContents
Sheets("searchresult").select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode-text", Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
Sheets("Show").Select
End Sub
```

This is what I want

```
Sub pastecontent()
Sheets("searchresult").UsedRange.ClearContents
Sheets("searchresult").PasteSpecial Format:="Unicode-text", Link:=False,   
DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
End Sub
```

Is it possible?
/Jens

Comment: Yes, it's definitely possible. Unless I'm mistaken `ClearContents` is also clearing the `Application.CutCopyMode`. Clear the contents first, *then* copy the source, and then immediately paste it. As it stands it doesn't look like you're copying anything. What's being pasted?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Better worded then mine, I was going to say copy the range and paste before you clear the range. +1

Comment: @GMalc if the range being cleared is supposed to be what's copied, then you're right it should be cleared last.

Comment: Hello! I'm copying content from another program. The content is already in the clipboard when the macro is started.

Comment: The `ClearContent` needs to run before data is in the clipboard then. Or can you paste to a new sheet?

Comment: Don't know why but the clipboard isn't erased with the Sheets("searchresult").UsedRange.ClearContents line. The first example in my post do paste the stuff in the clipboard just fine.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is then?

Comment: The problem is that the screen flashes between the two sheets. Searchresult and Show. The second example in my post is what I want. I want to paste the content in the clipboard to the sheet "Searchresult" without having to select it first. I want the sheet "Show" to be visible all the time and the pasting to happen in the background! :)

Comment: I see that. What I'm unclear about is what the problem is with the code you want, other than the missing ilne continuation. Getting any particular error? Tried pasing on A1? e.g. `Sheets("searchresult").Range("A1").PasteSpecial ...`

Comment: Wow it worked! But had to use xlPasteAll from the comment from Peter T below! See the finished code below in the answer below!

Answer (score 1):

It's very possible and even preferred to avoid using `Activate`. Look at [this webpage](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate) for a brief discussion. But you still have to copy data to the clipboard in order to paste. So building on your example:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PasteContentExample()
    Dim dataSource As Range
    Set dataSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("searchresult").UsedRange

    Dim dataDestination As Range
    Set dataDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("anothersheet").Range("A1")
    Set dataDestination = dataDestination.Resize(dataSource.Rows.Count, dataSource.Columns.Count)

    dataSource.Copy
    dataDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    '--- clear all data and formatting from the source area
    dataSource.Clear
End Sub
```

Notice this code doesn't clear the source contents until after it's been copied.

Also notice it doesn't need `Select` or `Activate` :)

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it to work! Thanks everyone! This is the code that did the trick:

```
sub pastecontent()
Sheets("privata").UsedRange.ClearContents
Sheets("privata").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
end sub
```

So simple!
Thanks again! :)
/Jens